# Smart Search on an Object on VF page

Tags: visualforce

I need to implement a smart search feature. It should produce results immediately as soon as users starts typing in smart search field. Lets say it starts search names in Account object.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by smart search? From your brief description it looks like you want the autocomplete feature, just guessing.  And also post in your code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Jeff Douglas's website: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/13/building-a-dynamic-search-page-in-visualforce/

The name fields use java script to send the keyed in value to the controller to build a dynamic soql query.

There are other ways of doing this though this is just one example.

Edit. Another approach is here http://www.michaelforce.org/recipeView?id=a0G30000006eVxVEAU. Michael again uses java script but waits for a second after the last keyed in value. This example is for searching products but is the same approach of "auto search".

I've tried both approaches,  they both work,  but I find if you type quickly the first approach can sometimes miss the lat character (none of my users have found this though).